PowerBI currently broken with BigQuery: Simba driver issue with windows update
I've been happily using PowerBI on Windows 11 with BigQuery for several weeks. After an update of Windows 11 today, I'm now getting this error:
Unable to Connect:
Details: "The 'Driver' property with value '{Simba Google BigQuery ODBC Driver}'
doesn't correspond to an installed ODBC driver."

What gives?
I've reinstalled PowerBI and Windows 11, and I still have the same problem.
I've tried installing the Google Driver by hand from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers
No joy :(.
Has anyone here experienced this before? Is it a local issue, or is it a new global issue with the recent Windows 11 update?
Thanks.

TL;DR it looks like the version in the Microsoft Store is currently broken. The version on the Power BI site works just fine, despite having the same version number as the store version). [See below to the accepted answer, thanks @gkohrell]

I looked into the forum that @Gisela linked, and they mentioned that you need to uninstall PowerBI and then reinstall it from the website (not the Microsoft store). You can download it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58494
It solved the problem for me, so I would definitely give it a try!

That worked for me, too. Interestingly, the version of the direct download and the version from the Microsoft store are identical!
This is the version that works for me [Version: 2.132.1053.0 64-bit (August 2024)]
I downloaded it from:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/products/power-bi/getting-started-with-power-bi#Desktop-app
(then select 'Desktop App' and 'Advanced Download Options' to get the working binary). To confirm, don't use the 'Download for Free' option, as that takes you to the store and that version doesn't work despite having the same version number.

Yeah I forgot to specify - the 64-bit version worked for me as well. Thanks for helping clarify!
